# replace only exact match with sed command

Tags: sed

I want to change some names in a file using sed.Here i want to replace word which contains only rohit.com with goyal.com.This is how the file looks like:

```
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName rohit.com 
 1.rohit.com
 rohit.coma
 rohit.com.abc  
 ServerAlias rohit.com
 rohit.com
```

I tried this

```
sed  's/\brohit.com\b/goyal.com/' a.txt
```

i received this output

```
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName goyal.com 
 1.goyal.com
 rohit.coma
 goyal.com.abc   
 ServerAlias goyal.com
 goyal.com
```

But expected output is :

```
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName goyal.com 
 1.rohit.com
 rohit.coma
 rohit.com.abc  
 ServerAlias goyal.com
 goyal.com
```

please guide me how to fix this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably your `sed` doesn't recognize `\b` as a word boundary. Try `\<...\>` and/or [edit] your question to clarify your OS and `sed` version.

Comment: As an aside, you need to escape the dot to only match it literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU sed solution like

```
sed -E 's/(\s|^)rohit\.com(\s|$)/\1goyal.com\2/g' a.txt
```

where `(\s|^)` matches and captures into Group 1 (`\1`) a whitespace or start of string, and `(\s|$)` captures into Group 2 (`\2`) a whitespace or end of string.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Fe4sbQ):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName rohit.com 
1.rohit.com
rohit.coma
rohit.com.abc  
ServerAlias rohit.com
rohit.com'
sed -E 's/(\s|^)rohit\.com($|\s)/\1goyal.com\2/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName goyal.com 
1.rohit.com
rohit.coma
rohit.com.abc  
ServerAlias goyal.com
goyal.com
```

If there can be consecutive matches, repeat the command:

```bash
sed -E 's/(\s|^)rohit\.com($|\s)/\1goyal.com\2/g;s/(\s|^)rohit\.com($|\s)/\1goyal.com\2/g' <<< "$s"
```

Comment: thanks but its just a  sample file rohit.goyal and goyal.com will come dynamically from variables

Comment: @ROHITGOYAL And what is the problem? [Use your variables in `sed`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
var=goyal

cat > ed1 <<EOF
/ServerName/
s/rohit/$var/
/ServerAlias/
s/rohit/$var/
wq
EOF

ed -s file < ed1
```